# Neural Network Console (NNC)で作成した画像認識用学習モデルをspresenseで実装しようとしたが

Tags: spresense

NNCで作成した鯨と海を識別する画像認識用学習モデルをspresenseを用いて、arduino ideで実行したのですが、画像右のシリアルモニターの反応が k1.jpg is -1 のように「-1」となっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プログラムは以下リンク先の手順に従い作成しました。

[SPRESENSEでSony Neural Network Console を使ってみた！](https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-07-14)

それによれば、-1のところは本来、識別する画像が鯨か海かを
0~1の確率で表記されるようになっています。
なお今回の場合0に近いほど鯨と認識するようにしています。
全て-1と表示されるため画像認識どころではありません。
-1と表示されるのはなぜなのでしょうか。

ソースコード自体がグレースケールの画像を識別しているので、
RGBの画像が対応していないだけなのでしょうか。

また自分が調べたところ、dnnに使えるファイル形式はpgm形式でないとだめというコメントを確認しました。
NNCによる学習モデル作成では、公式の動画でjpgでも大丈夫とのことだったので
それに従いjpgで作成しました。NNC上では普通に動作しましたが、
公式の動画ではspresenseに実装する動画は現在までにアップされていません。
spresenseで動かすとなるとファイル形式は改めなければならないのでしょうか。

参考となる回答をよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

サイトを参照していただきありがとうございます。

**結論から言いますと、Spresense の DNNRT への入力に、jpg画像をそのまま使うことはできません。**

NNCはjpgデータをピクセルデータに復号してニューラルネットワークに入力しているのでjpgも扱えるようになっているようです。（学習データにjpgを使ったこと無いので推測です）

なぜ自信満々にそう言えるかというと、ニューラルネットワークの ”inputレイヤー” 定義をみれば一目瞭然です。

”inputレイヤー” のパラメータが「1,28,28」になっている場合は、(1,28,28) の行列を入力するという意味になります。つまりモノクロの28x28のピクセルデータに展開しなければネットワークに入力できません。

カラー画像の場合は、「3,28,28」に ”inputレイヤー" が定義されます。これは(3,28,28)の行列の入力、つまりRGBの28x28のピクセルデータを入力するという意味になります。ですのでjpgデータは事前にRGBの画像に展開されていなければなりません。

Spresense の場合は組み込みなので、NNC ほど親切ではありません。DNNRTに入力する場合は、あらかじめ圧縮された画像は展開しておかなければなりません。（さらにデータをピクセル毎に、0.0-1.0の間に正規化して入力する必要があります）

jpg画像を扱いたい場合は、Spresense にjpgデコーダを組み込んでおき、jpgデータをピクセルデータに展開する必要があります。（ただし組み込むのは大変です。お勧めしません）

さらにカラー画像を DNNRT に入力する場合は注意が必要です。カラーのデータはRデータ、Gデータ、Bデータのブロック単位で DNNRT に入力する必要する必要があります。すなわちRGBのピクセルデータを分解し、Rデータ、Gデータ、Bデータのまとまりにする必要があります。これは、"inputレイヤー" の行列の構造が(3,28,28) となっていることを考えれば分かると思います。

例えば、カメラのRGB565（16bit）のデータを扱う場合はこんな感じになります。

```
  uint16_t* buf = (uint16_t*)img.getImgBuff();

  DNNVariable input(INPUT_WIDTH * INPUT_HEIGHT * 3);  
  float* r = input.data();
  float* g = r + INPUT_WIDTH * INPUT_HEIGHT;
  float* b = g + INPUT_WIDTH * INPUT_HEIGHT;
  for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_WIDTH * INPUT_HEIGHT; ++i) {
   *(r++) = (float)((*buf >> 11) & 0x1F)/ 31.0; // 0x1F = 31
   *(g++) = (float)((*buf >>  5) & 0x3F)/ 63.0; // 0x3F = 64
   *(b++) = (float)((*buf)       & 0x1F)/ 31.0; // 0x1F = 31
   ++buf;
  }
  dnnrt.inputVariable(input, 0);
  dnnrt.forward();
  DNNVariable output = dnnrt.outputVariable(0);
```

このような背景があるので、Spresense で画像ファイルを扱う場合は単純なフォーマットである [PNM](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNM_(%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88)) がよいと言われているのだと思います。ただ、PNMしか使えないのもPCで作業する上では不便ですよね。

なので、私は Spresense でBMPを扱えるライブラリを作ってみました。

https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/BmpImage_ArduinoLib

このライブラリですが、BMPの構造上、無駄にパレットを使うのでSpresenseでは小さな画像しか扱えません。（もともとDNNRTで小さい画像を扱うことしか想定しておらずメモリ最適化していません）

もし、必要だったら使ってみてください。ただし、出来たてほやほやなので、実装上の不具合がたくさんあると思います。使用の際はは自己責任にてお願いします。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。
まさかサイト主さんから直接回答頂けるとは思ってませんでした。

プログラムやハードを最近になって扱いはじめたもので、
ファイル形式やpcのこと、その他様々なことについての知識が
圧倒的に不足しております。
そのあたりの情報は知らなかったので、とても助かります！
組み込み型とそれ以外とでは気を遣わないといけないのですね。

spresenseをリアルタイム(30fps)で使えるようにしたいことや
そこまで処理速度が高くないことも考えると、
spresenseにデコーダを積んで内部で処理させるのはあまりやりたくないですね。

RGBの方が画像認識的には精度が上がるようですが、
その分処理も重くなってしまうので、
pc内でjpg画像をpnm形式に変換させた上で学習からやり直した方が
効率的ですか？　pnmが不便な理由も分かっていない状態ですが...
この場合カメラモジュールから取得した動画に画像認識を直接行うことも可能でしょうか？

今の自分のスキルでは、BMPをうまく扱えないと思うので、
現状では使わないです。すみません。

Comment: PNMは普通の画像処理ソフトではサポートしていないので画像の確認ができないのが難点です。ただ、ImageMagick（https://imagemagick.org/index.php）というソフトを使うとPNMも扱えます。コンソールで利用できるので便利です。Spresenseの場合は、むしろカメラから直接処理したほうが便利だと思います。こちら（https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2020-02-18）にカメラを使った（白黒ですが）サンプルがありますので参考にしてください。カラーにしたい場合は、回答にあったやり方でDNNRTにつっこんであげればOKです。その際に、NNCのinput をRGBが受けられるよう（例えば 3,28,28 とか）にしてあげてください。

Comment: 確かにPNMに画像を変換したところ、Windows上では画像として見れませんでした。
「可視化」という点において確かに扱いにくいですね。  カメラから画像認識するため、そちらのサイトを参考にやってみようと思います。
またなにかあれば別途質問するかと思います。
良ければそのときにも回答して頂けるとありがたいです。
ありがとうございます。